# Opening internal files Android

Tags: android, xml, file, webview

There is an XML file on my companies web drive that can be viewd in a web browser.

The file looks like this:

```
http://nkm18ar8/TGStatxml/xml1.xml
```

Which means it is an XML file.

Now i want to make a mobile android application so that all of the workers who are on the internal network can view it

For this ive created a webview and tried to load the Uri of the file path.

Sadly, However this did not work.

There are many reasons why i want to view this file in a webview one of them is that every 5th second the website updates and the data that the file shows updates aswell which is a critical part of the application.

Now my question is how would you go around opening files like that in android? and is it even possible?

Comment: On some corporate networks, they do blocking based on device, user agent, etc. Have you asked the network admins?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String html = "";
InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
str.append(line);
}
in.close();
html = str.toString();
```

change url to the path of the xml file, then add a textview to your layout and somewhere in your code set the text of the textview to the html String

and remember in you manifest to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

EDIT: This will let you see the actual xml of the file if that is what you are trying to view